# Crontab Issues running Python

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get cron to run this command every 10 minutes;

(In /home/pi/myst-myst/ DIR)

```
python myst.py `./monitor.sh`
```

I've tried pretty much everything to get it to work but cron won't execute it properly. Here is what I have at the moment;

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py `./monitor.sh`
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Is there an alternative to crontab I could use? Could I use a bash script to execute python and then use a cron for that bash script?**

Comment: ehat exactly means "won't execute it properly"? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: I can't find anything in the logs that's relevant..

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems calling both python and perl directly from cron.  For perl it boiled down to  LIBPATH defaulting to something insufficient.

I'd suggest wrapping your commands in a shell script and adding "set -x" to trace through the problem

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
export PYTHONPATH=/my/python/modules:$PYTHONPATH
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py $(/home/pi/myst-myst/monitor.sh)
```

Call it directly to make sure it works, and then try calling via cron.  Make sure to redirect both stdout and stderr to capture any error messages

```
 */10 * * * * /home/pi/myscript.sh > /home/pi/stdout 2> /home/pi/stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
*/10 * * * * cd /home/pi/myst-myst/;/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py $(./monitor.sh)
```

to change working directory before running the command.

Edit: replaced backticks

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Even this doesn't work properly; sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py `/home/pi/myst-myst/monitor.sh`

Comment: You probably should add some output to your script (myst.py), but two things I can spot are that the backticks seems to make problems in crontab in my experience and should be replaces by $(command), and that you need the 'cd /home/pi/myst-myst;' part or ./monitor.sh won't work since it won't be in the current directory.

Comment: I've modified it to match yours and still doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Does your script rely on any environment variables, such as `PYTHONPATH`?
If so, the environment will be missing when invoked by cron.

You can try:

```
*/1 * * * * PYTHONPATH=/my/python/modules/ /usr/bin/python /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py `./monitor.sh`
```

Comment: that don't work because the current directory of a cron is not the one of monitor.sh

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
 */1 * * * * /home/pi/myst-myst/myst.py `./monitor.sh`
```

And add the following in myst.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: that don't work because the current directory of a cron is not the one of monitor.sh